# Why TS is not resolving Omit properly

Tags: typescript

I have this snippet:

```js
const func = <T>(e: T & { id: string }): T => {
    const { id, ...rest } = e
    return rest
}
```

I don't understand why Typescript seems to think that `Omit<T & { id: string }, 'id'>` is not equivalent to `T` and do I have a better alternative than using `as unknown as T` in order to make it work?

---

#### EDIT

```
const func = <T extends { id: never }>(e: T & { id: string }): T => {
    const { id, ...rest } = e
    return rest
}
```

This does not work either, even if I'm guaranteed by using `never` that the input didn't have an id before I added one to build `e`.

Comment: They're not equivalent because T might include an id even before it's `&`'d with `{ id: string }`. For example, what if T is `{name: string, id: string}`? Your current code tries to return a `{name: string}`, but that doesn't match T. What would you like to do in a case like this? Or do you want this case to be impossible, and T cannot include an id?

Comment: Yes, I think I do actually. I expect T to have an id of type string but to split this object into its parts with its id on one side and the reste on the other, I'm interested in getting the rest.
What I think is: if I have T that have no id and I add an id on top of it then I split, I should fall back to what I started with no?

Comment: Yes it does in fact but Nicholas Tower's answer is less noisy and more understandable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is that `T` could have an `id` property on it, even before it's combined with `{ id: string }`. Your return type says you'll return a `T`, so for the case where T has an id, you need to include an id, but your current code does not do so.

From the comments, it appears the object passed in should always have an id, and the object that's returned should always *not* have an id. To do this, i recommend that you change the meaning of T, so that it defines the value being passed in, not the value being returned:

```
const func = <T extends { id: string }>(e: T): Omit<T, 'id'> => {
  const { id, ...rest } = e;
  return rest;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAKjApgDylzABMIYBvGASxIC4ZoAnasAcxgF8A%20AClwZYAlAwDyAW2pRsAGhgByWvO5oVFALAAoGDFCRYVWnIB0pprmhc0eANxad5qAiZgY56Hc2ctWvZfcIADaw6IjIvFRgAIbiAgoARiDx8nK0DPJwICDynEI2QA)

P.S: your edited suggestion with `extends { id: never }` won't work because `T & { id: string }` means that id must simultaneously be a `string` and `never`. `string & never` is the same as `never`, and so you cannot pass an id into a function with that type.

Comment: *"if T doesn't include an id, then you need to not return an id"* - not technically true. If `T` is `{foo: string, id: string}` then `Omit<T, 'id'>` is `{foo: string}`, but an object like `{foo: 'bar', id: 'baz'}` is assignable to that type. Something of type `T` is always assignable to a type of the form `Omit<T, K>` due to structural subtyping.

Comment: @kaya3 Good point. Updated my answer.

Comment: As a side note, if you want the return type that is hinted to actually be `{ foo: string }` rather than `Omit<{ id: string, foo: string}, "id">`, use `Omit`'s source directly: `{ [P in Exclude<keyof T, "id">]: T[P]; }` as the return type ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAKjApgDylzABMIYBvGASxIC4ZoAnasAcxgF8A+AClwZYAlAyoBtAAo0wMAKL5gAGwQlcGANa4AniDgwsAGhgAiWse4BdQZIsBuLmm6UAsACgYMUJFhVaRgHSBTLjQDui4tm4ewVAITDLB0JGunG5uXqGJCIqw6IjIvFRgAIYAtgIwAOQARiDVlUa0DJVwICCVnEK2QA)). The function definition won't be pretty, but the returned types will be.

Comment: Also it's probably important to highlight that `...rest` will only pick up *enumerable* properties from T, not all of its properties as defined by the type. Typescript will think the non-enumerable properties are present, but at runtime they would be omitted from the returned copy.